# Drupal DB size increasing while delete pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have to build a site in drupal. I already have the similar drupal site. So i cloned it. I planned to remove unnecessary pages (20 pages). I got removed those pages. After this delete action, DB size increased. I assumed that as per logic, db should decreased but in my case it increased from 18 mb to 30 mb. I m using drupal 7.

I have no idea how to optimize it, i m front developer. Anybody can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your site is generating content on it's own, i.e. maybe it's parsing some feed and generating content from it?

Other possibility is that db increased because of cache, if cache is turned on. But DB size increase is too big, so I doubt. Anyway, you can try clearing the cache and see what will happen (regarding DB size of course).

Last possibility I can think of is that you site has been hacked.